# JQuery replaceWith function not replacing the div it's targetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an external js file that does the replacing:

```
function test()
{
    alert("here");
    $('#thisDiv').replaceWith(
        '<a href = "index1.php">Test1</a>\
        <a href = "index2.php">Test2</a>');
}
```

And in my HTML source code I have:

```
<div id = "thisDiv">
    <a href = "old_index1.html">old_test1</a>
    <a href = 'old_index2.php'>old_test2</a>
</div>
```

The alert is running fine which means I have no issues calling the test() function. However after the function finishes the page still has old_test1 and old_test2 on it. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the function in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar no i am not. I am running an if statement and if something is true, I call the test() function.

Comment: You have to be sure that `thisDiv` exist by the time you call `replaceWith`. You can debug what ` $('#thisDiv').length` returns

Comment: @ClaudioRedi that's interesting. I outputted that function into an alert and it returned 0 'alert($('#thisDiv').length);' returned 0

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in your file inside of a `$(document).ready()` callback, to make sure the div is present on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
});
```

Also, if you want `thisDiv` to remain, instead of `$('#thisDiv').replaceWith(newHtml)`, you could use `$('#thisDiv').html(newHtml)`.

Comment: So i did that and the changes are made. The issue is I only want to replace the div if a something is true.